# How to transfer files from Azure Data Lake Gen2 to GCS

Tags: airflow

I am using Airflow version 1.10.12.

1. Is there any operator in this version of the airflow to copy files from Azure Data Lake Gen 2 Blob storage to Google cloud Storage.
2. Do we install PyPi Package to overcome this deficiency

Answer (score 1):

First of all let me state that Airflow 1.10 reached end of life on June 17 2021 and will not be supported even for security fixes. 1.10.12 is pretty old version and you should migrate to 2.0 soon (now!).

Regarding your question about operators - Airflow 2.0 has a number of providers defined and you can easily browse them and see them here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/  - those are all providers/operators currently supported.

You can look at the list of operators for Microsoft Azure:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure/stable/operators/index.html

And Google:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/transfer/index.html

You can look them up and see if any of those solve your problem. I do not think there is directly an operator that you need. But even ff not, it is not a problem as long as you have the right Hooks it should be rather easy to combine several hooks and build your own custom operator

Azure Data Lake Hook is there: [Azure Data Lake Hook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure/stable/_api/airflow/providers/microsoft/azure/hooks/azure_data_lake/index.html)

Similarly Google cloud storage:
[GCS Hook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/gcs/index.html)

So this should be very easy to build your custom operator to do what you want  - you can take for example AzureFileShare->GCS and build very similar operator:

[AzureFileShareToGCSOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/azure_fileshare_to_gcs.html#AzureFileShareToGCSOperator)

Just follow [Create custom operatpr](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/custom-operator.html) guide.

Comment: I am using ADLSToGoogleCloudOperator for connecting to Azure Data Lake Gen 2 and copying the files in the Blob Container. However, the host value shows as host='accountname.azuredatalakestore.net', port=443. Is this operator by default resolving the hostname to azuredatalakestore.net?. Is there any way to change the host name?

Comment: What is the connection you are using? You need to create the right connection to connect to your Azure Storage Data Lake

Comment: Conn Type : Azure Data Lake and ADLSToGoogleCloudStorageOperator